# I have a very humid room in the house, should I isolate it?

Tags: humidity

My house has a room very humid (85%) and susceptible to temperature changes. Even opening the windows I have mold issues sometimes. The other part of the house is well isolated and acceptable regarding humidity.

Is it best just to isolate this room  from the remaining house by keeping its door closed, avoiding air humidity and cold to propagates through the remaining house? Or in other hand would it be better just to keep it open transferring part of this humidity and therefore keeping the average level lower in this room?

Around the room there is the bathroom, street, roof and ground. The humidity is mainly for 2 reasons. 1. Bathroom wall; 2. exterior walls. Most likely the neighbour garden.

Comment: We need more details.  Why is this room humid?  What's next to it on all six sides?

Comment: @Bryce I just updated the question.

Comment: -1 for wanting to ignore a problem rather than fix it.

Comment: @BMitch sorry, but I don't agree. I don't want to ignore, but these things don't solve by magic and it will take time to sort everything out. Plus it's a rented house and I can't invest too much in it.

Comment: Getting a dehumidifier takes less time than this question has been open, no magic involved. Ask your landlord if they'll be willing to pay for it while they figure out the moisture problems. Assuming the bathtub isn't overflowing, this is their problem to fix.

Comment: Is this a grow house?

Comment: @auujay, sorry what do you mean?

Comment: @BMitch If I could I would have done so instead of asking. Unfortunately this is not an option and I am really looking for a simple answer. Is it better to have room high on moist or try to lower that by opening the room to the remaining house.

Comment: The big problem in a grow house (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grow_house) is the humidity that results from it.

Comment: @auujay thank you for your creative comment. At least now I know what that is.

Comment: @nsn, we've explained why the two options you provided are bad. You haven't explained why a dehumidifier is not an option for you. If you're not willing to fix it right the first time, then be ready to spend the time and money to undo the problems your first fix caused and then fix it right the second time.

Comment: @BMitch it't not an option because I think this should be fixed. Unfortunately it will take time and patience  for sure. Meanwhile I was trying to find a way of making the environment (%moist, temperature) a bit better without spending money on a dehumidifier.

Comment: If you're unwilling to use a dehumidifier (guess you want a zero-cost fix?) then you need to find the source of the humidity/leak. As @BMitch points out, just being near bathroom walls or having gardens outside does not cause excess humidity. There must be a source of water, and you have to find and eliminate it. Closing off the room will just make things worse, by creating mold and spores that will quickly end up requiring major renovations (replacing all drywall, for example) and it it WILL spread to the rest of the house (via air spaces in the wall, incomplete seal, opening the door, etc).

Comment: Grow houses require quite a bit of ventilation. You'll likely have to install a large exhaust fans to deliver the excess humidity to the outside, as well as a fan to provide fresh "make up" air to replace the exhausted air. The amount of ventilation required, will depend on the number of plants.

Answer (score 2):

Bathroom walls don't create excess humidity unless there's a leak or you aren't running the exhaust vent. The same goes for exterior walls/roof/ground. You need to find the source of the moisture and eliminate it. Trapping the moisture in one room where there's a leak will only make the problem in that room worse. And spreading mold spores throughout the house is only going to make any reaction to them worse.

Comment: Thanks. I understand, but this is a short term solution. I need to solve it, but I need to take action in the next few days, and I was just wondering which option would be the best.

Comment: The best short term solution is to put a dehumidifier in the room.

Comment: Not an option for now :)